# Error al intentar borrar un objeto serializable de un archivo

Tags: java, serialización

Muy buenas estoy intentando hacer un ejercicio, y me pide que para borrar un objeto, creo un archivo temporal y cuando coincida el idMueble del que quiera borrar no lo escriba en el temporal.
Pero no soy capaz de dar con el problema, no me hace hace nada, termina con la excepcion de final del archivo y ya esta

```
    public static void borrarMueble() {
    File archivoTemporal = new File("MUEBLES_TEMP.DAT");
    ObjectOutputStream escritura = null;


    try (ObjectInputStream lectura = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File("MUEBLES_OBJ.DAT")));) {
        Mueble m;
        int idMuebleBorrar = buscarIdMueble();
        escritura = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(archivoTemporal));

        while (true) {
            m = (Mueble) lectura.readObject();
            System.out.println(m.toString());
            if (m.getIdMueble() != idMuebleBorrar) {
                escritura.writeObject(m);
            }
            escritura.close();
        }

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Utilidades.visualizarMensaje("Fin del fichero");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Archivo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
```

La excepción que me da es Errorjava.io.IOException: Stream Closed

Comment: Buenas tardes Luis. Puedes agregar la salida completa de la excepción por favor?

Comment: si no me equivoco estas trabajando sobre el mismo archivo con output e inputStream que es lo que te debe estar dando error